# Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не могу разобраться?

Tags: c

```
// talkback.c - Демонстрация и взаимодействие с пользователем
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>　　 // Предоставляем прототип функции strlen ()
#define DENSITY 62.4　　// Плотность человеческого тела (единица: фунты / кубические футы)
int main()
{
float weight, volume;
int size, letters;
char name[40];　　　 // имя - это массив, который может содержать 40 символов
printf("Hi! What's your first name?\n");
scanf("%s", name);
printf("%s, what's your weight in pounds?\n", name);
scanf("%f", &weight);
size = sizeof name;
letters = strlen(name);
volume = weight / DENSITY;
printf("Well, %s, your volume is %2.2f cubic feet.\n",
    name, volume);
printf("Also, your first name has %d letters,\n",
    letters);
printf("and we have %d bytes to store it.\n", size);
return 0;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не могу разобраться ! В чем проблема:
DENSITY не работает, спецификатор %s не работает, scanf не
работает.Заранее Огромное Спасибо!

Comment: Напишите условие задачи. Фраза не работает -  ничего не объясняет.

Comment: Вообще-то у вас какие-то "левые" непечатные символы имеются... после `<string.h>`, `DENSITY 62.4`, `char name[40];`. Если их убрать, все компилируется и более-менее работает...

Comment: L'　' - Символ: U+3000 Название: IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде присутствуют символы UTF-8. Это широкие пробелы L'　' - Символ: U+3000 Название: IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE. Некоторые символы компилятор может обрабатывать в именах переменных, а их список в стандарте такой :

> Annex D (normative)
> Universal character names for identifiers
> This clause lists the hexadecimal code values that are valid in universal character names in identifiers.

> D.1
> Ranges of characters allowed
> 00A8, 00AA, 00AD, 00AF, 00B2–00B5, 00B7–00BA, 00BC–00BE, 00C0–00D6, 00D8–00F6, 00F8–00FF
> 0100–167F, 1681–180D, 180F–1FFF
> 200B–200D, 202A–202E, 203F–2040, 2054, 2060–206F
> 2070–218F, 2460–24FF, 2776–2793, 2C00–2DFF, 2E80–2FFF
> 3004–3007, 3021–302F, 3031–303F
> 3040–D7FF
> F900–FD3D, FD40–FDCF, FDF0–FE44, FE47–FFFD
> 10000–1FFFD, 20000–2FFFD, 30000–3FFFD, 40000–4FFFD, 50000–5FFFD, 60000–6FFFD, 70000–
> 7FFFD, 80000–8FFFD, 90000–9FFFD, A0000–AFFFD, B0000–BFFFD, C0000–CFFFD, D0000–DFFFD,
> E0000–EFFFD

> D.2
> Ranges of characters disallowed initially
> 0300–036F, 1DC0–1DFF, 20D0–20FF, FE20–FE2F

Ваши пробелы с кодом U+3000
*(UTF-8: 0xE3 0x80 0x80

Восьмеричный код в UTF-8 на языке C: \343\200\200 )*
не позволено находиться в Си коде.
Удалите их и будет компилироваться.

Comment: Сделал ровно все что вы сказали, проблемы исчезли, но все равно не компилируется. Компилятор пишет:Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка  'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.  D:\Project\Project2\Blasphamous.cpp 11 
Хорошо, вместо функции scanf пишу scanf_s. Начинает компилировать, как только ввожу в консоль любое слово и нажимаю enter выдает еще ошибку:

Comment: __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl __report_gsfailure(GSFAILURE_PARAMETER)
    {
        if (IsProcessorFeaturePresent(PF_FASTFAIL_AVAILABLE))
        {
            __fastfail(FAST_FAIL_STACK_COOKIE_CHECK_FAILURE);
        }

        volatile UINT_PTR cookie[2];

Comment: Про `scanf` это всего-лишь предупреждение. Ваш компилятор выпендривается. можете для надёжности написать так : `scanf("%40s", name);`. Про функцию `scanf_s` ничего не скажу, надо читать документацию про неё.

Comment: В этом компиляторе это считается за ошибку, которая не дает запустить код((((. А может быть проблема в спецификаторе %s? Потому что, когда меняю его на другой то выдает просто один символ либо рандомный набор символов.

Comment: вроде надо так : `scanf_s("%39s", name, 40);` [scanf_s, _scanf_s_l, wscanf_s, _wscanf_s_l](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, незнакомец!!!